# Событие выделения текста через Shift

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как в JS можно отследить выделение текста с помощью клавиши Shift и стрелок (без мыши).

У меня реализован сайт, где при выделении текста над этим текстом появляется некий элемент. Это работает с мышью - отслеживаю `mouseup` и `click`. Как отслеживать событие когда текст выделен с помощью Shift + стрелка?

Comment: А как же `Ctrl + A`  ?

Comment: не нужно отдельные комбинации клавиш отлавливать.[GlobalEventHandlers.onselectionchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onselectionchange)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, завтра попробую

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, прекрасно работает, оформите в ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете отслеживать комбинации клавиш которые нажимает пользователь.
Писал с jQuery

```js
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 37) {
        console.log('Нажаты Shift и ←');
    }
    if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 39) {
        console.log('Нажаты Shift и →');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чистый JS.
 getSelection() возвращает объект selectionRange 
 toString() меняет в строку.

```js
function getSelectedText() {

    if (window.getSelection()) {

        let select = window.getSelection();

        alert(select.toString());

    }

}
```